# My Django App works on my local development server but does not work on my Linode VPS

Tags: python, django, linode

I have the exact same code deployed locally on development server and Linode Virtual Private Server. The Local site works fine, but when I try to access the same url on the VPS, I see this in the browser:

```
This site can’t be reached XXX.XXX.XXX.X refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Even when I go to the admin site it is broken.
I have narrowed the change down to my views.py and settings.py file changes, as I was making one code change at a time to try and find out where the VPS did not like my code. I am unable to understand why the Django App just seems to break.

My views.py function, the last line of code will be called:

```
def start_or_end_fast(request):  
 
 if request.method == 'POST' and 'start_fast' in request.POST:
  start()
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('start_or_end_fast'))
  
 elif request.method == 'POST' and 'end_fast' in request.POST:
  print('mmmmm')
  end()
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('start_or_end_fast'))

 elif request.method == 'POST' and 'duration' in request.POST:
  duration = time_difference()
  return render(request,'startandstoptimes/index.html', {'duration': duration})

 else:
  return render(request,'startandstoptimes/index.html')
```

settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

#Xs to mask IP on Stackoverflow
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.X','127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'startandstoptimes.apps.StartandstoptimesConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DjangoApp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoApp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I am thinking there may be some configuration on my server on something that needs changed, I am stumped.

Comment: Is there a firewall configured?

Comment: Good point I will check that but my app did work when it was basic then stopped once \i add mode code to my views but thanks for the tip